как использовать в питоне html разметку
возможно ли как-нибудь выводить в терминал текст отформатированный html рaзметкой?

Если кратко: Нет. Но можно сделать что-то похожее самому. Есть библиотеки поддерживающие красивый вывод в терминал, например: https://github.com/Textualize/rich

Есть библиотека html2text. Конвертирует HTML в приличный Markdown.

Нет. В консоли используются коды ANSI:
BLACK = "\033[0;30m"
RED = "\033[0;31m"
GREEN = "\033[0;32m"
BROWN = "\033[0;33m"
BLUE = "\033[0;34m"
PURPLE = "\033[0;35m"
CYAN = "\033[0;36m"
LIGHT_GRAY = "\033[0;37m"
DARK_GRAY = "\033[1;30m"
LIGHT_RED = "\033[1;31m"
LIGHT_GREEN = "\033[1;32m"
YELLOW = "\033[1;33m"
LIGHT_BLUE = "\033[1;34m"
LIGHT_PURPLE = "\033[1;35m"
LIGHT_CYAN = "\033[1;36m"
LIGHT_WHITE = "\033[1;37m"
BOLD = "\033[1m"
FAINT = "\033[2m"
ITALIC = "\033[3m"
UNDERLINE = "\033[4m"
BLINK = "\033[5m"
NEGATIVE = "\033[7m"
CROSSED = "\033[9m"
END = "\033[0m"
print(RED + "123" + END)


Это будет рабоать только в *nix консоли (возможно в новом терминале Windows). В "старой" консоли windows нужна будет colorama.

Colorama - это те же ANSI-коды, только старые

Старые или новые - без разницы. Без нее в старом терминале Windows никакие не будет работать.
